# How to add new line code in a single cell of SQL 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I was trying to bring a line break in a single cell of sql. But still I am not getting a line break. My sample code is,

```
DECLARE @SubName VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @SubName = SubCode FROM @SubjectList WHERE ID = @Counter 
SELECT @SubName = @SubName + CHAR(13)
SELECT @SubName = @SubName + SubjectName FROM @SubjectList WHERE ID = @Counter 
SELECT @SubName = @SubName + CHAR(13)
SELECT @SubName = @SubName +'Max :' + COALESCE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),internalmarks),'NA') FROM @SubjectList WHERE ID = @Counter
```

My o/p display is,

[image]

My expected o/p is,

```
 MA(101)
 Calculas
 MAX:20
```

In a single sql cell. Please help me. I am using it inside of a stored procedure. When I run in a new query window it gives the expected output to me.But this same query not works inside of my stored procedure

Answer (score 0):

For `\r\n` you need to use `CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)`:

```
DECLARE @SubName VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @SubName = SubCode FROM @SubjectList WHERE ID = @Counter 
SELECT @SubName = @SubName + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
SELECT @SubName = @SubName + SubjectName FROM @SubjectList WHERE ID = @Counter 
SELECT @SubName = @SubName + CHAR(13)+ CHAR(10)
SELECT @SubName = @SubName +'Max :' + COALESCE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),internalmarks),'NA') FROM @SubjectList WHERE ID = @Counter;

PRINT @SubName;
```

Warning:

You won't see effect using `SELECT` in SSMS datagrid. You need to print it out or use Application Grid (C#/Java):

```
DECLARE @SubName VARCHAR(100);

SELECT @SubName = 'aaa';
SET @SubName += CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'bbb';
SET @SubName += CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'ccc';

PRINT @SubName;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/381555)**</kbd>

Comment: ,Still o/p like "MA 101   Calculus   Max :20"

Comment: @SemilSebastian SSMS datagrid won't break up and does not allow \r\n in presentation. But the newline is there. See updated

Comment: See my updated question please. It works,if I run this outside of my stored procedure.It miss behaves only within my Stored Procedure.

Comment: @SemilSebastian I don't see your stored procedure and how you call it. I cannot recreate your case

Comment: lad2025,My SP is too much big.Unable to update here. Any other way to show you?

Comment: Ok wait a moment please

Answer (score 0):

you cannot add new line / page break code to show in table sql server.
save your time to search that problems.

Comment: Really unable to add line breaks inside a table??

Comment: really bro. cannot using page break in cells table to show in sql server. but if u still want to see page break u must using gridview for example in visual studio.